# Datepicker not working inside <th> element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the *Bootstrap datepicker*. However, I am trying to use it inside a *table* and, to be specific, inside a *th* element. Here is my table:

```
        <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-height="400" data-pagination="true" data-locale="en_US">
```

And inside that, I have:

```
      <th data-field="date" >
          <div  class="input-group bfh-datepicker" data-format="y-m-d" data-max="today" id="input-date" placeholder="Date of record">
        </div>
      </th>
```

The problem is, I cannot get the datepicker to display properly. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: share live demo if possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this code to your CSS to the datepicker window that is hidden now:

```
element.style {
   position:relative;
   z-index:1000; //change your number as per elements lies on your page.
}
```

Comment: Although is not exactly what I wanted, it solves my problem for now.  I added this to ".bfh-datepicker-calendar"